# Serialize single variable of an object into a single value using json Writes in Play 2.1

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I am using Play 2.1.1 with Scala. I want to be able to serialize an object into a single value so that I can toss them into a list and have it output an array of this object. I only want it to output entry.document.

```
import play.api.db._
import anorm._
import anorm.SqlParser._
import play.api.Play.current
import java.sql.ResultSet
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.Json.toJson
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.JsValue


implicit val searchEntryWrites = new Writes[SearchEntry] {
  def writes(entry: SearchEntry): JsValue = {
    Json.obj(
        toJson(entry.document)
    )
  }
}
```

entry.document is actually already JSON. I have figured out how to get this to compile but the output is escaped json instead of just json. Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the type of `SearchEntry.document`? Or, could you add the definition of `SearchEntry` to your question? Just the (case) class, not the companion object (if you have one).

Comment: Could you also include the imports and what the compiler exception is too?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do it like that without first parsing the values with the play JSON library, so that you will have a JSObject representation of the json in entry.document.

Maybe it would be better to not parse it and just build the JSON string yourself in this case? Something like:

```
Ok("[" + entries.mkString(",") + "]").as("text/json")
```